# akka remote actor running on local actor

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-stack, akka-remote-actor

I am learning `akka-remote` and trying to re-do http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-sample-remote-scala myself.

When I try to run the project in two separate JVMs, I see

```
$ clear;java -jar akkaio-remote/target/akka-remote-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.harit.akkaio.remote.RemoteApp ProcessingActor

ProcessingActorSystem Started
```

and

```
$ clear;java -jar akkaio-remote/target/akka-remote-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.harit.akkaio.remote.RemoteApp WatchingActor

WatchingActorSystem Started
asking processor to process
processing big things
```

I asked my `Processing System` to run on port `2552`

```
include "common"
akka {
  # LISTEN on tcp port 2552
  remote.netty.tcp.port = 2552
}
```

and I told my other system (`WatchingSystem`) to run on port `2554` but start `processingActor` on port `2552`

```
include "common"

akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
      "/processingActor/*" {
        remote = "akka.tcp://ProcessingActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"
      }
    }
  }
  remote.netty.tcp.port = 2554
}
```

and `common` is about using the right provider

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Questions/Concerns**

1. From logs, I see that the `processingActor` is running on `WatchingActorSystem` and not on `ProcessingActorSystem`, what is wrong going on?
2. How can I see that the two ActorSystems are connecting to each other. I do not see logging happening. However, in the example, I shared the logging happens. What am I missing?

The entire code is posted on [Github](https://github.com/hhimanshu/akkaio) and runs as well

Answer (score 0):

1) Your deployment configuration is set up to have all the children of processingActor being remote, as described in the [akka configuration docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#Actor_Deployment_Configuration)

You should set it to this instead:

```
deployment {
  "/processingActor" {
    remote = "akka.tcp://ProcessingActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"
  }
```

2) You need to set your log level to something useful as described in the [akka logging documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html#Auxiliary_logging_options)